# Static code analysis for Grails/groovy project

Tags: grails, groovy, sonarqube, codenarc

If I use sonarqube as static code analysis tool for grails project after installing groovy plugin in sonar, then does it also internally use codenarc or do i have to use codenarc analysis of project separately using codenarc plugin in grails?

Basically, is sonarqube sufficient for static code analysis or should i also use codenarc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sonar groovy plugin relies on codenarc to do its analysis. So using SonarQube or Codenarc is just a matter of how you want your results to be displayed and/or if you want to share tracking of issues in your code with your team. In the end, you should have the same results but SonarQube will bring you more functionality to track issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to also format & fix your groovy files, you can use :

- [npm-groovy-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-groovy-lint) with command line
- [VsCode Groovy Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint) with Visual Studio Code UI